# Storing Lua function for later use in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I am using [lua-intf](https://github.com/SteveKChiu/lua-intf) to integrate lua into my project. I want to setup a lua function that takes in a function as an argument and that then gets stored in C++ and called at a later time.
This would be the lua code for example where I would store both of these functions in C++:

```
foo(bar)
foo(function() print("bar") end)
```

I have tried using LuaRef as an argument but couldn't get it to work, I have also tried setting the argument as a lua_Cfunction.

Comment: Why did your attempts fail? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you've tried and what problems you encountered

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lua registry is probably the easiest way. For more on the registry, see [this page](https://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.1.html).

As an example, here is a C function called `lua_foo` that shows how to store a reference in the registry:

```
int lua_foo(lua_State* L) {
    // Make sure a function has been passed.
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TFUNCTION);
    // Make sure that the function is at the top of the stack.
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
    // Create a reference to the function using the Lua registry.
    int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    // FIXME: do something with the reference or store it for later use.
    return 0;
}
```

In order to store the function passed to `lua_foo` for later use, see [`luaL_ref`](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_ref); and, for the freeing of such a resource held by the Lua registry, see [`luaL_unref`](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_unref).

From within your C function, use `luaL_ref` to create a reference, which is an integer, for later use. The function, whose reference key is returned by `luaL_ref`, can be retrieved using `lua_geti`. Once retrieved, the function is pushed onto the Lua stack and can be called.

Alternatively, you can dump the function--as you would with a call to `string.dump`--and store the string result for later loading and use. Admittedly, this approach is a little more involved.